# js function is not defined in django template

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, static

I have just started learning Django and I tried to add simple js static file to my Django template. However I am not able to execute function in Django template due to `Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not definedat HTMLButtonElement.onclick`.
My function is very simple and it is within static folder at the project level `static/js/script.js`

```js
function myFunction() {
    alert("This is result of JS function!");
}
```

At the project level I have the `base.html` within `templates/base.html`. Here it is:

```html
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" scr="{% static 'js/script.js' %}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="nav-bar">
      <a href="{% url 'myapp:home' %}">Home</a> | 
      <a href="{% url 'myapp:about' %}">About Us</a> |
      <a href="{% url 'myapp:services' %}">Our Sevices</a> | 
      <a href="{% url 'myapp:info' %}">Info</a> |
    </div>
    <div class="page-content">
      {% block content %} 
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <div class="page-footer">
      <a href="#" >Usefull links</a> | 
      <a href="#" >Follow Us</a> |
      <a href="#" >Address</a> |
      <p  id="copyright">&copy; 2022 Learning Django</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

At the app level I have folder `templates` and inside several html files like `myapp/templates/myapp/services.html`.

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %} 
{% load static %} 


{% block title %}Our Services{% endblock %} 

{% block content %}
<h1>This is Our services page</h1>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos sint
  necessitatibus omnis dicta nobis! Quam, vero natus! Blanditiis tempore
  deserunt unde, voluptatum quo dolore. Optio alias sed numquam eligendi ex!

<button onclick="myFunction();" type="button">Click me!</button>
</p>

{% endblock %}
```

My templates load other static files such as css and img without any problems. However template `services.html` cannot call `myFunction()`.

Could you please help me to solve this problem. It feels to me that I am chasing my own tail.

Answer (score 0):

It was as simple as adding `<script src= "{% static 'js/script.js' %}"></script>` below the  tag in `services.html` template.

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %} 
{% load static %} 


{% block title %}Our Services{% endblock %} 

{% block content %}
<h1>This is Our services page</h1>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos sint
  necessitatibus omnis dicta nobis! Quam, vero natus! Blanditiis tempore
  deserunt unde, voluptatum quo dolore. Optio alias sed numquam eligendi ex!

<button onclick="myFunction();" type="button">Click me!</button>
<script src= "{% static 'js/script.js' %}"></script>
</p>

{% endblock %}
```